# Get variable from URL with Jquery Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am doing a jquery refresh on a div containing a mysql query. The query however needs to grab a variable from the URL. It works, but as soon as it does the refresh it stops grabbing the variable and thus the query doesn't work.

Here is my refresh code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#records').load('user_records.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 30000); // refresh every 30 seconds
</script>
```

and then my basic query...

```
    $username = $_GET['user'];
    echo $username; //for testing
    echo "<div id='records'><h1 align='center'>Today's Transfers</h1>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
    <th> Customer Name</th><th>Phone Number</th><th>Disposition</th><th>DID</th><th>Date Called</th>
    </tr>
    ";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $user_id = $row['id'];
}
```

followed by echoing my results, etc, etc.
The query gets the username and works when the page load, but when it does the refresh it stops getting ther $username variable, even though it is still in the url. Is there a way to keep getting the variable each time? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is the second code block the code that is in the "user_records.php" file?

Comment: your not passing the $_GET variable in your jQuery ... `$('#records').load('user_records.php?user=some_user').fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: How would I get the user variable into the jquery code?

Comment: Do you have any _HTML_ object in the first file that contains the _Username_ ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to pass the user to the server. If you can access the username in javascript somewhere you can do the following.

```
$('#records').load('user_records.php?user='+username).fadeIn("slow");
```